# Disconnect between :dynamic metadata and actually-dynamic Vars in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and am playing around with dynamic scope. I've discovered a few things:

- Adding `{:dynamic true}` metadata to an existing Var doesn't actually make the Var dynamic. I can kind of see why you'd want this to be the case, but it can be misleading.
- You can see if a Var is actually dynamic with `(.isDynamic #'whatever)`
- You can (but probably shouldn't?) change whether a Var is dynamic with `(.setDynamic #'whatever)`

In short, it looks like the dynamic nature of a Var is stored in the guts of the clojure.lang.Var class itself, and setting `^:dynamic` metadata *at def time only* will affect that internal state. Changing metadata afterward doesn't appear to affect it. OK, fine.

I discovered this when I was looking at the dynamic variables in namespace clojure.core. I checked to see what Vars in that namespace have `:dynamic` metadata set:

```
user=> (def metadyn (map key (filter #(-> % key resolve meta :dynamic) (ns-publics 'clojure.core))))
#'user/metadyn
user=> metadyn
(*3 *2 *print-level* *data-readers* *e *print-length* *1 *verbose-defrecords*
*clojure-version* *default-data-reader-fn* pr)
```

Rather fewer than I expected, missing things like `*out*` and `*in*`.

I checked to see what Vars actually *are* dynamic:

```
user=> (def realdyn (map key (filter #(-> % key resolve .isDynamic) (ns-publics 'clojure.core))))
#'user/realdyn
user=> realdyn
(*compile-path* *3 *2 *ns* *print-level* *allow-unresolved-vars* *data-readers*
*unchecked-math* *math-context* *read-eval* *compile-files* *command-line-args*
*warn-on-reflection* *e *flush-on-newline* *out* *print-length* *1 *file* *verbose-defrecords*
*clojure-version* *use-context-classloader* *err* *default-data-reader-fn* *agent* pr
*print-dup* *print-readably* *fn-loader* *print-meta* *in* *source-path* *compiler-options* *assert*)
```

Lots more.

So, the following Vars are dynamic but don't claim to be in their metadata:

```
user=> (clojure.set/difference (set realdyn) (set metadyn))
#{*compile-path* *ns* *allow-unresolved-vars* *unchecked-math* *math-context* *read-eval*
*compile-files* *command-line-args* *warn-on-reflection* *flush-on-newline* *out* *file*
*use-context-classloader* *err* *agent* *print-dup* *print-readably* *fn-loader* *print-meta*
*in* *source-path* *compiler-options* *assert*}
```

My question is simply: is there any significance to this, something I'm missing? Or, is it just a case of sloppy bookkeeping in the Clojure implementation?

No practical use for this; just trying to Understand.

Comment: They are created in the runtime before def is available.

Comment: Thanks, good enough for me. If you put it in a reply, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic vars you have identified without metadata are those created in the Java runtime (see [RT.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/96f5b5bdcae44ccc69e33d701e6188dc2570dadf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java) starting around line 180). The others are created in Clojure after the bootstrapping has made `def` available (i.e. within core.clj and core_print.clj).

Metadata could have been added later and in some cases was (e.g. `*agent*` has a docstring), so this is not a complete answer. I could speculate that lack of practical importance, as you point out, has made truing-up the metadata of the vars used in bootstrapping a low priority.